# -features=groovy generates java Application class

Tags: micronaut

Just generated a groovy service app with
    mn create-app my-groovy-app -features=groovy
and it produced a java Application class.

I was expecting a groovy Application class. Is this going to change?

Comment: Possibly, but it doesn't really matter what language the `Application` class is written in.  The feature support has more to do with the capabilities related to the ability to use Groovy to implement other parts of the application.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this going to change?

Yes.  The change has been made and will be in the next milestone (M2).